# JPA & Spring- how to obtain the shared EntityManager from spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, clojure

I'm using JPA with Hibernate on Spring 3.0.

I have defined a `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `JpaTransactionManager`.
All the Daos have an `EntityManager` (i guess a shared one) injected with `@PersistenceContext`, but i have some code where I'd like to use the same `EntityManager`, but fetch it manually. How to accomplish that?

When I just resolve `EntityManagerFactory` bean and call `createEntityManager`, this `EntityManager` is separate from the one which Dao's use (so when i find() and object via DAO, i cannot persist it using manually obtained `EntityManager` - entity is detached).

Answer (score 5):

There is one way, but you should be certain that you really need that. In almost all cases you can inject the entity manager.

Here's how to do it if no other option exists:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = obtainEntityManagerFactory(); // you mentioned you have it
EntityManagerHolder holder = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(emf);
EntityManager em = holder.getEntityManager();
```

In short - for each transaction started by the `JpaTransactionManager` spring stores the entity manager in a `ThreadLocal`, using the factory as a key.

Comment: I need it because I want to use it in Clojure code (no annotations there, I host spring context inside a Clojure app). I'm unable, however, to unwrap Proxy hiding EntityManagerFactory object - and so i'm unable to use it in getResource. I tried to cast the Proxy to Advised and getTargetSource(), but without luck.

Comment: I can't help with clojure. I'll retain the answer for the sake of others having a similar question.